# Javascript date validation not working

Tags: javascript

so i'm trying to validate my date input by using a European format so it can be easily inserted into my database. I'm getting an error message pop up trying to tell me to use the required format however after changing the regular expression about a billion times i still can't seem to get it working.

Below is my JS script that is called when i hit the insert button.

```
     function checkForm(form)
  {
    // regular expression to match required date format
    re = /^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/>

    if(form.startdate.value != '') {
      if(regs = form.startdate.value.match(re)) {

             // year value between 1902 and 2017
        if(regs[1] < 1902 || regs[1] > (new Date()).getFullYear()) {
          alert("Invalid value for year: " + regs[1] + " - must be between 1902 and " + (new Date()).getFullYear());
          form.startdate.focus();
          return false;
        }

        // month value between 1 and 12
        if(regs[2] < 1 || regs[2] > 12) {
          alert("Invalid value for month: " + regs[2]);
          form.startdate.focus();
          return false;
        }
           // day value between 1 and 31
        if(regs[3] < 1 || regs[3] > 31) {
          alert("Invalid value for day: " + regs[3]);
          form.startdate.focus();
          return false; 
        }

      } else {
        alert("Invalid date format: " + form.startdate.value);
        form.startdate.focus();
        return false;
      }
    }
  }
    </script>
```

This is what calls the insert php file (which deals with the sql side of things) and should called the above JS function. I'm not sure if the error is because i'm also insert a int amount as well as the data within the same submit button.

```
<form action="insertCarb.php" onsubmit="return checkForm(this)" method="post">
Carb Amount: <input type="text" name="CarbAmount" required/><br>
Date: <input type="text" name="Date" required pattern="/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/><br>
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: What error message are you getting? Can we see some test case dates that are valid and invalid?

Comment: This should be valid = "2017-05-31".
This should not valid  = "31-05-2017"

The message is "Please match the requested format" (it's an information popup)

Comment: And this 2017-5-1 too?

Comment: i don't mind at this point making the user have to add the 0 on single digit day and month values

Comment: Why is there a `>` after the regex? Also, `if(regs = form.startdate.value.match(re))` should use a `==`.

Comment: thankyou for the help, still getting the errors

Answer (score 0):

You may change the following code:

```
<input type="text" name="Date" required pattern="/^(\d{4})-(\d{1,2})-(\d{1,2})/" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
```

To:

```
 <input type="text" name="Date" required pattern="\d{4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2}" placeholder="yyyy/mm/dd"/>
```